# Correlation between strings within variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How could I assess the correlation between each type within each variable?

```
df
      level            job
0     good           golfer
1     bad           footballer
2   intermediate     musician
...
```

Expected Output is a correlation table or something similar to this:

```
             golfer  footballer  musician  ...
good      
bad       
intermediate
```

I tried:

```
df['level']=df['level'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['job']=df['job'].astype('category').cat.codes
df.corr()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by correlation in the context of categorical variables, but maybe you can take a look at the pivot and pivot_table methods.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: For example, I'm trying to see if golfers more likely to be in the "good" category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.level, df.job)
df1
```

For my example data you get the output

```
job           footballer  golfer  musician
level
bad                    1       3         3
good                   3       3         2
intermediate           1       2         2
```

And divide by the sum of every row

```
 df1 / df1.sum()
```

Output

```
job           footballer  golfer  musician
level
bad                  0.2   0.375  0.428571
good                 0.6   0.375  0.285714
intermediate         0.2   0.250  0.285714
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the expected output you want to have a table of frequencies. I guess this could be done better but one approach is:

```
count_combos = pd.Series(zip(df.level, df.job)).value_counts()
count_combos.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(count_combos.index)
count_combos.unstack()
```